# Can't use returned parsed JSON

Tags: javascript, meteor

In one of my helpers I have the following code

```
Template.App.onCreated(function() {
    this.settings = new ReactiveVar([]);
    Meteor.call('settings', (error, result) => {
        this.settings.set($.parseJSON(result));
    });
});

Template.App.helpers({
    data: function() {
        console.log(Template.instance().settings.get());
        return Template.instance().settings.get();
    }
});
```

It calls to a method that executes the following code

```
return Assets.getText('settings.default.json');
```

And in the console it would print

[image]

But when I try to use it in my template like this

```
{{#each data}}
    {{this.public.hello}}
    {{this.public.public.hello}}
{{/each}}
```

Neither works. No errors or anything anywhere. It displays nothing.

Why is this?

Comment: Your `data` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: It's like baao says, you're returning the result from `Meteor.call`'s callback function, so that the data ends up inside the data function. You need to grab the data from the callback and then return it after `Meteor.call`'s semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I defined a variable before the meteor call and assign the result to it, but when I return the variable after the meteor call the variable is undefined.

Comment: Can you show that code? Is the callback async? Like, is the variable even being written to before returning from `data`?

Comment: Your edited code looks like to should work. Try with explicit data context aka {{# each foo in bar}} {{foo.baz}} {{/each}}